# Bootstrapping survival data to obtain confidence interval for a function of median survival time

Tags: survival, bootstrap

I have a group of survival data, mature enough so that its sample median can be estimated by Kaplan-Meier method. I'm hoping to estimate a quantity which is an increasing function of the median, and plan to use bootstrap to obtain a 95% confidence interval.

My question is, for each iteration of the bootstrap, there is a good chance that Kaplan-Meier estimate for median may not exist because the re-sample itself may not be mature enough. Is there any way around this? e.g. set the "not reached" median as Inf and proceed as usual?